# Cannot connect to internet in Backtrack 5 R3

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, backtrack

I am running a full installation of Backtrack 5 R3 on my computer (no VM) and have a working ethernet connection to the local network. I am able to access the intranet sites, but cannot access the internet. How can I go about fixing this? I can provide more information easily.

As a side note, the local network requires a SonicWall login for access to the internet. I can login fine, but could Sonicwall be causing the problem?

Comment: Yes, please provide more information.  IE: Can you expand on "cannot access the Internet"?  Like, can you ping by IP?  Can you ping by name? Can you reach your Internet gateway?  If you do an `nslookup` for an Internet domain name, does it resolve correctly?  Have you discussed your situation with the admin of the Sonicwall?

Comment: @techie007
Ping by both IP and name works and `nslookup` works fine. I ran the pings and `nslookup` on Google and Yahoo and got back working IPs for both.

Comment: @techie007 Talked to the local admin. He has no idea, not a Linux guy.